# Does Oracle 10g comply with the ANSI SQL-1992 substring function standard?

Tags: sql, oracle, ansi-sql, ansi-sql-92

According to the [ANSI SQL-1992 standard, page 132](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt), this is the syntax for the ANSI substring function:

```
<character substring function> ::=
    SUBSTRING <left paren> <character value expression> FROM <start position>
    FOR <string length> ] <right paren>
```

A quick test in SQL developer on an oracle 10g schema:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('ASDF' FROM 1 FOR 1) FROM DUAL;
```

Results in:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 28
```

Does this mean Oracle 10g does not comply with this particular ANSI standard?

I simply would like to use an ANSI standard substring function instead of a vendor specific one.

Comment: yup i think it does not comply

Answer (score 6, accepted):

oracle documentation for [SUBSTR](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm)

but you can check this http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#functions-SUBSTRING

> Doesn't provide the standard SUBSTRING
>   function. Provides
>   SUBSTR(input,start-pos[,length])
>   instead (i.e. length is optional). 
>   Oracle provides a number of
>   SUBSTR-variants (SUBSTRB, SUBSTRC,
>   SUBSTR2, SUBSTR4, same syntax as for
>   SUBSTR), mainly for handling various
>   kinds of non-latin-only string-types. 
>   Oracle doesn't have support for
>   string-extraction with the special
>   SQL-style regular expressions.
>   Instead, it has the REGEXP_SUBSTR
>   function which offers string
>   extraction, using POSIX-style regular
>   expression pattern matching.

Comment: Also take a look at [Oracle Compliance To Core SQL:2003](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/ap_standard_sql003.htm#sthref10080).  "Oracle has equivalent functionality for these subfeatures:", "E021-06, SUBSTRING function: use SUBSTR function instead".

Comment: C'mon, how hard can it be for Oracle to add a SUBSTRING function? I see that it has a specific syntax (rather than being a plain function), but SQL is already full of this.

Comment: @marcus Probably just a minor modification in the lexer.

Answer (score -5):

Try this

SELECT SUBSTRING('ASDF' ,1,1) FROM DUAL;

It will work in any standard

Comment: -1 Doesn't answer OP's question and is wrong - the Oracle function is SUBSTR.

Comment: The OP wants to use ANSI standard SQL, not vendor proprietary lock-in SQL.